# How do I debug a script relying heavily on an existing Illustrator document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS5 and ExtendScript Toolkit CS5.

I've got a very involved script and alert() isn't working anymore because stuff is within a loop. How can I simulate the fact that I'm using a specific Illustrator document so that I can use the debugging features of ExtendScript Toolkit?

I want it to be the same as being inside an Illustrator document and going "File->Scripts->Scriptname". If I just test the script inside ExtendScript, I get an error on

```
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved!

I had to change the target application to Illustrator within ExtendScript Toolkit and set the debug level to `$.level=2`
to get it to work properly. I can now have breakpoints and all that good stuff.

Comment: How to you set the target application?